# Link shared object library without including it

Tags: c

I am developing a library. The library will be compiled into a shared object (.so). To use the library, https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html says I need to both #include the header (.h) file and link the shared library -lmylib. They say the header file should contain function prototypes for the functions to be used while the actual code for the functions would be in the (.c) file.

I tried compiling my code without #including the header file, and I receive and undefined reference error from the compiler, but it compiles successfully when the header is included.

If I leave off the header I get both implicit declaration warnings and undefined reference errors :

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printmatrix’
undefined reference to `printmatrix'
```

However, the lapack function that I am calling does not need a header. It receive an implicit declaration warning but no error:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘dsyev_’
```

Why do I need to include the header file? It appears I am incorporating the header file into the final code twice, once while compiling the shared object and again when compiling the executable. I have used other libraries, e.g. lapack where I can link the library without any #include statement.

Comment: I don't think you get undefined reference for not including a header, you would get such an error when linking. Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Do you know how header files work?

Comment: @immibis, a header file essentially pastes its contents into the file during precompilation. It is like concatenating the files.

Comment: headers generally have function prototypes/signatures/declarations. This just tells the compiler "there's a function called `printmatrix` and it takes these arguments and returns this type". The compiler complains about an implicit declaration when you try to call a function whose signature it has no knowledge of. The "undefined reference" is a linker error (linking happens after compilation). This is the linker saying it can't find the definition (the actual code) of `printmatrix`. This code is presumably in your `.so` file.

Comment: You're thinking about it wrong.  The form of the code after preprocessing is not a significant concern.  Although each translation unit that `#include`s your header will after preprocessing contain the header's contents, who cares?  As long as your headers contain only declarations and maybe macro definitions, as they should, then nothing in them ends up in the compiled binary.  But they do affect how the compiler constructs the stuff that *does* go in the binary.

Comment: I see. I have reserved .c for executables and shoved most of the essentials of my code into .h files. I will change this library over to the convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, headers should only contain declerations: types, structs, function prototypes, classes, templates, etc... not code (unless it's for error handling).

Headers are useful because they allow you to set the same exact declarations for both the library (the .so) and the interface to the library (the executable elf that will use the shared object).

In order for linkage to complete successfully, your application should know the calling convention of the function: it may be a c-style call (cdecl), pascal style (WINAPI), fast-call or others - each one has a different method for calling.

If you really don't want to use the libraries headers you can also define functions manually, using the `extern` keyword. It would probably just be the same like re-writing the header file(s) all over again (not recommended).

For example, If the shared library has a `add()` function:

```
    int add(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
    }
```

And you want to use that function within your application without a header, you could do this:

```
    extern int add(int, int);

    int main() {
      int a = 10, b = 20;
      int r = add(a, b);
      printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, r);
      return 0;
    }
```

> It appears I am incorporating the header file into the final code twice, once while compiling the shared object and again when compiling the executable.

That's how things should be done. You should include the same header in both project. Most major libraries do that. See [libevent](https://github.com/libevent/libevent) for example.

Comment: No, in general header files should contain only *declarations*.  Definitions are exactly what they should not include.

Comment: Also, although you certainly *can* use `extern` to declare a function, and doing so is harmless, it is unnecessary because external linkage is the default.  The situation is a bit different for variables, however.

Comment: I see how adding the line with extern is essentially the same as including the header file which contains the function declarations, however I am still curious as where my computer gets the declaration for dsyev_ from. There was no header or declaration involved. It must have received everything it needed from the -llapack option. Why can my libraries not do this?

Comment: @TonyRuth It seems that your compiler is guessing the prototype of the functions you are calling hence the warning `implicit declaration of function`. If the compiler doesn't guess correctly you will start seeing segfaults.

Comment: @TonyRuth, your computer *does not* get a declaration for `dsyev_`.  It has to guess, based on your usage.  Most compilers will do this for you, because it was specified by the original ANSI standard and was supported by pre-standardization C, but since C99 it is non-standard to call a function that does not have an in-scope declaration.  And it is risky, too, because the compiler can guess wrong.